# Файловый менеджер C# Ошибка Перемещение файла

Tags: c#

Столкнулся с такой проблемой, что не могу переместить файлы с дисков С и D, которые уже были созданы на нем, как я понимаю дело все в правах доступа, подскажите, куда смотреть??[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

"Исключение, возникающее в случае запрета доступа операционной системой из-за ошибки ввода-вывода или особого типа ошибки безопасности." Попробуйте запустить собранный .exe файл от имени администратора. Возможно пользователь под которым запускается сборка не имеет текущих прав администратора для доступа в не пользовательские папки(корень c; windows; и т.д.) Разумеется, обычно пользователь имеет возможность повысить себе права нажав "запустить от имени администратора". В c# можно намеренно запрашивать такой доступ, прописав в свойствах проекта манифест.